# Xen hvc0 console size

Tags: xen, console, guest

Hello I got a Xen running using hvc0 for the guests. Everything works fine except for the size  (lines and rows) of the console: It's always 80x25 what makes editing awkward sometimes. If the line one edits gets too long, the cursor jumps one line up, cuttig the first part of the already written line. Is there a way to prevent that behaviour?
That happens when accessing the console with putty aswell as with VGA

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR, no. Xen still can't use anything different that 80x20 on hvc0.
// to be honest, I don't like that behaviour too.